# Excel VBA to Python code (Filter function)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to python. Some help would be great, thanks in advance too. I am trying to get the various average salary based on Units.

In Excel, I would do `=AVERAGE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D3))`. Where Column B is all the individual salaries and Column A is the various Unit.

I have managed to do an array of the different units:

`DiffUnits = df["Unit"].unique()`

My data:

| Units | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 500 |
| Math | 3000 |
| Math | 1200 |
| Science | 700 |
| IT | 2000 |
| Science | 1800 |

Expected result (In the form of a table, if possible):

| Units | AverageSalary |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 1250 |
| Math | 2100 |
| Science | 1250 |

Comment: In Excel, you could have used [`AVERAGEIF/S`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Units': ['IT', 'Math', 'Math', 'Science', 'IT', 'Science'],
                   'Salary': [500, 3000, 1200, 700, 2000, 1800]})

df2 = df.groupby('Units').mean().reset_index()

df2
```

gives you:

```
     Units  Salary
0       IT    1250
1     Math    2100
2  Science    1250
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know 1 line would work already...

Comment: Use `as_index=False` argument of `groupby` and avoid `reset_index`.